# Comparing two instances of same objects in Drools

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I have a model object Account

```
package com.drool.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Acccount {

    private int id;
    private int balance;
    private Date transDate;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public Date getTransDate() {
        return transDate;
    }
    public void setTransDate(Date transDate) {
        this.transDate = transDate;
    }



}
```

DroolsRule

```
import com.drool.model.Acccount

rule "accountTransaction"
when
$first : Acccount()
$second : Acccount( this != $first, transDate==$first.transDate )
then
System.out.println("second Accounbt had latest transaction");
end
```

Test Application Code:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("HelloWorld.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
Acccount account = new Acccount();
account.setBalance(1000000);
account.setId(123);
account.setTransDate(new Date());
Acccount account1 = new Acccount();
account1.setBalance(200);
account1.setId(1234);
account1.setTransDate(new Date());
ksession.insert(account);
ksession.insert(account1);
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Output:

```
second Accounbt had latest transaction
second Accounbt had latest transaction
```

I am new to drools and when I run the above sample . The result is printed twice which should be ideally printed only once. Please let me know if my Rules are correct?

Answer (score 0):

A pair of constraints like this one:

```
$first : Acccount()
$second : Acccount( this != $first, transDate==$first.transDate )
```

is bound to fire twice, if it fires at all. With two Acccount facts of the same date, fact A is bound to `$first` and consequently fact B is matched and bound to `$second`. But the symmetry of A and B is not broken by the constraint, and therefore the same happens all over again, with A and B exchanging roles.

To avoid this, use a unique property with an ordering relation, presumably `id`:

```
$first : Acccount( $id1: id )
$second : Acccount( id > $id1, transDate==$first.transDate )
```

Answer (score -2):

What would you do if you want to compare two instances of the same class using the "Account (name=" format.